# Excel Test Length of 1 field and divide if len>200

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have column **B** that I need to test the length to see if it is longer than 200 characters.  If it is longer than 200 characters, I need it to go from right to left and find the occurrence of the semicolon ";" and split the field from the right of the semicolon into column **C**.  Can this be done?  Before I was having to do this with 4 columns and have reduced it to one column.  Please advise to the best formula to do this.

Comment: If you want the residue (left hand part) put back in column B, I would use a macro.

Comment: I have always found it a bit curious that the find or search functions in Excel don't have an option to find the last occurrence of a character as this strikes me as something that could be a fairly common requirement. I have written a function named FindLast below which could be used as a custom equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

`=IF(LEN(B1)>200,MID(B1,SEARCH("@",SUBSTITUTE(B1,";","@",LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,";",""))))+1,LEN(B1)),"")`

Explanation:

1. Remove all instances of the delimiter: `SUBSTITUTE(B1,";","")`
2. Subtract the length of (1) from the length of the entire string to get the number of occurrences of the delimiter: `LEN(B1)-LEN([1])`
3. Substitute the last occurrence of the delimiter with an @: `SUBSTITUTE(B1,";","@",[2])`
4. Find the location of the @: `SEARCH("@",[3])`
5. Get the substring of everything to the right of the @ location: `MID(B1, [4] +1,LEN(B1))`
6. Add if condition to only process strings of length > 200: `=IF(LEN(B1)>200,[5],"")`

Comment: Nice solution, which I believe would be better with an explanation going along with it.

Answer (score 1):

I searched the web for formulas for this and concluded that you either need a lot of nesting and a difficult to follow formula or a VBA function. I would suggest using a VBA function such as the one I have written below (FindLast) within a simple formula. Let me know if you need instructions on how to create this VBA formula:

```
Function FindLast(find_text As String, within_text As Range) As Double

    Dim i As Integer

    i = Len(within_text.Value) ' start at last character and work back

    Do While Mid(within_text.Value, i, 1) <> find_text
        i = i - 1
    Loop

    FindLast = i

End Function
```

You will then be able to use FindLast within a formula such as the below in C1:

```
=IF(LEN(B1)>200,MID(B1,FindLast(";",B1)+1,500),"")
```

**UPDATE**

The 500 in the above is just a long number I picked to mean the rest of the cell. If there may be more than 500 characters after the final ; then use a larger number. Unfortunately I don't think the MID function allows you to specify that you want to return the rest of the cell. I have put to return nothing if B1 is not >200 characters, let me know if this is not the requirement.